# R WebCrawler - XML content does not seem to be XML:

Tags: xml, r, statistics

I took the following code from the rNomads package and modified it a little bit.

When initially running it I get:

```
> WebCrawler(url = "www.bikeforums.net")
[1] "www.bikeforums.net"
[1] "www.bikeforums.net"

Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'www.bikeforums.net'
```

Here is the code:

```
require("XML")

# cleaning workspace
rm(list = ls())

# This function recursively searches for links in the given url and follows every single link.
# It returns a list of the final (dead end) URLs.
# depth - How many links to return. This avoids having to recursively scan hundreds of links. Defaults to NULL, which returns everything.
WebCrawler <- function(url, depth = NULL, verbose = TRUE) {

  doc <- XML::htmlParse(url)
  links <- XML::xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
  XML::free(doc)
  if(is.null(links)) {
    if(verbose) {
      print(url)
    }
    return(url)
  } else {
    urls.out <- vector("list", length = length(links))
    for(link in links) {
      if(!is.null(depth)) {
        if(length(unlist(urls.out)) >= depth) {
          break
        }
      }
      urls.out[[link]] <- WebCrawler(link, depth = depth, verbose = verbose)
    }
    return(urls.out)
  }
}


# Execution
WebCrawler(url = "www.bikeforums.net")
```

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Hello guys,

I started this bounty, because I think in the R community there is need for such a function, which can crawl webpages. The solution, which would win the bounty should show a function which takes two parameters:

```
WebCrawler(url = "www.bikeforums.net", xpath = "\\title" )
```

- As output I would like to have a data frame with two columns: the website link and if the example xpath expression matches a column with the matched expression.

I really appreciate your replies

Comment: If you run
`doc <- XML::htmlParse("http://www.bikeforums.net"); links <- XML::xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")` manually it works but within the function (using debug mode) doc comes back empty... this is strange

Comment: Try with `url="http://www.bikeforums.net"` and let me know

Comment: @dimitris_ps When I run `> WebCrawler(url="http://www.bikeforums.net")` I get`Error: failed to load external entity "/"`

Comment: @Floo0 yep it is really strange. I also added now `rm(list = ls())` and cleaned my workspace several times as before. Any recommendation what could be wrong here?

Comment: @mrquad The second error is due to the fact, that there are relative-links on the website. Ofc `"//a/@href"` also greps href's like `/` but `/` itself is not a website. So you have to check if the link is relative of absolute. If it is relative you have to convert it propperly. In this example convert `/` to `http://www.bikeforums.net/`

Comment: Hey guys, 11 upvotes, but no new answers.  I really would appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

Insert the following code under `links <- XML::xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")` in your function.

```
links <- XML::xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
links1 <- links[grepl("http", links)] # As @Floo0 pointed out this is to capture non relative links
links2 <- paste0(url, links[!grepl("http", links)]) # and to capture relative links
links <- c(links1, links2)
```

And also remember to have the `url` as `http://www......`

Also you are not updating your `urls.out` list. As you have it, it is always going to be an empty list of length the same as the length as `links`

Comment: Maybe i am mistaken but `links <- links[grepl("http", links)]` excludes relative links e.g. `/archive/index.php/` would be excluded this way would't it?

Comment: Hi, what does "Also you are not updating your urls.out list" mean? I am also getting the same error. How can I make sure it updates?

Comment: This part `urls.out <- vector("list", length = length(links))` just creates every time an empty list.